# Angular 6 *ngFor loop through an two array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

i have two array

```
 firstArray= [{id: 1, name:'firstValue1'}, {id:2, name:'firstValue2'}]

 secondArray= [{ "num": 1, "fullName": SecondValue1 , id:1}]
```

i want to show data like this

```
firstValue1 -------->> SecondValue1

firstValue2 -------->>
```

How can i populate this two array in [(ngModel)] or input or select box?

Thankyou for your time and response!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of maintaining `secondArray` as `Array` convert it to `HashMap`

**Example**

```
firstArray = [
    { id: 1, name:'firstValue1' }, 
    { id: 2, name:'firstValue2' }
];
secondArray = { 
    '1': { "num": 1, "fullName": "SecondValue1", id: 1 },
    '2': { "num": 1, "fullName": "SecondValue2", id: 2 },
}
```

**html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of firstArray">
    <p>{{item.name}} --> {{secondArray[item.id]?.fullName}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add an index manually to your `secondArray`, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstArray = [
    { id: 1, name: 'firstValue1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'firstValue2' }
  ];

  secondArray = [
    { "num": 1, "fullName": 'SecondValue1', id: 1 },
    { "num": 2, "fullName": 'SecondValue2', id: 2 }
  ];

  getSecondArrayItem(id) {
    return this.secondArray.find(item => item.id === id);
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of firstArray">
    <p>{{item.name}} --> {{ getSecondArrayItem(item.id)?.fullName }}</p>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmhnbi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Sidd, Your code works, but if the function is more complex, It's better create an auxiliar array because getSeconArrayItem are executed several, several several times along live of component

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what exactly do you mean by *How can i populate this two array in [(ngModel)] or input or select box?*

Comment: see issues here: ==> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fabmfb?file=src/app/app.component.html